# in mercurial what is the best way to ignore changes to a file without removing the working copy from anyone's repository

Tags: mercurial

I don't want this file to be removed from other developer's machines, but I don't want it tracked anymore either.  It is basically a setting file, that shouldn't have been checked in in the first place.

I think I have to tell the other developers to back up this file.  Then I can do a remove, and add it to the .hgignore.  Then they have to put the file back into their working directory.

It seems like hg forget would only work for my machine, and then next time another developer does a pull it would wipe out their file.

Any tips?

Comment: MQ-patches on top of common skeleton?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't need to back it up.  It's backed up in the repository.  You might want to get them to commit their latest version before they pull from you so they don't lose their latest changes.  When they lose their file they can just do `hg log <file>` and then `hg revert <latest revision - 1> <file>` to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like hg forget would only work for my machine, and then next time another developer does a pull it would wipe out their file.

Yes, non-versioned file will be saved (some time) only in your WC

If you don't want kill file and just ignore, you can

- use -X filename on commit by hand (or write in aliases section)
- install (on all workplaces) [Exclude Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExcludeExtension) (semi-automated solution from p.1)